# I can't store first , last name and email in django admin panel

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms

**forms.py**
this is my form

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .models import Profile

class UserSignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=50)

    class Mate :
        model = User
        fields = ['username' , 'email' , 'first_name' , 'last_name' ,'password1' , 'password2']
```

**views.py**
this is the Sign-Up Function

```
from django.shortcuts import render , redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .forms import UserSignUpForm
# Create your views here.

def SignUp(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserSignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request, f'your account has be created ! Now Log In{username}!')
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        form = UserSignUpForm()
    return render(request, 'forms/SignUp.html' , {'form' : form})
```

I've seen a lot of tutorials and they're doing the same thing

Answer (score 1):

Typo of `class Mate :` in `UserSignUpForm`. It should be `class Meta :`

```
class UserSignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=50)

    class Meta :
        model = User
        fields = ['username' , 'email' , 'first_name' , 'last_name' ,'password1' , 'password2']
```